# Awareness of the difference free/libre/open-source software and zero-cost software

Tags: software

Often when talking to friends or family they are unaware that open source is a completely different thing than free-ware.

Are there studies about the awareness of open-source being a separate thing from free-ware/spyware/malware/adware, at least in certain milieus?

Comment: [Closely related question](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/571/168)

Comment: Like always, please please tell us reasoning for down votes during this critical stage of site development.

Comment: @Zizouz212 There are 4 close votes cast. I think that's your answer.

Comment: That is no reason for a down vote. If something seems opinion based, thats reason for a close vote, not a down vote. Not only that, but we're also asking for explanation for all close votes.

Comment: My impression is that this is not general knowldge - I've noticed that some of the big downloads sites even use the same label - Freeware - for anything that is available to users without cost, and this is where the general public learns about most software.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I have not voted on this question, I understand your sentiment and no I don't know why the downvotes are cast if it isn't for the reason I previously stated. I think it's solid though.

Comment: @Mast I'm not saying that would've. But during a private beta, explanations are critical to help change the site tone and quality.

Comment: I think conflating freeware with spyware/malware/adware makes the question quite complex to answer properly. There are at least three issues to address: FLOSS/freeware confusion, freeware/malware confusion, and perhaps the repackaging of FLOSS with adware on some sites...

Comment: https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=open%20source%2C%20proprietary%20software%2C%20software%20license%2C%20free%20software%2C%20freeware&cmpt=q

Comment: Just show [this one-minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHF3xcWnSD4) to people who don't understand that free software is not a synonym of gratis software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common misunderstanding for Free software is thinking as free of charge/cost. If any one just search in google : [download free software](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=download+free+software) or [free software for...](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=free+software+for) then s/he is actually responded with [freeware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeware). But If anyone just tries to search [What is free software](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=what+is+free+software) then s/he is going on right way!

---

Following topics may helps you to aware the people:-

- Aware people with [**Software License**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license) to clarify what different terms stands for.

  [image: screen-shot]

  So, It is clear that spyware/malware/adware are **deceptive and/or illicit** while free software, open source software are software distributed under free/open-source license and follows definitions

  Freeware is [one type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software#License) of proprietary software (distinguishing with commercial software)
- The English adjective free is commonly used in one of two meanings: "for zero price" (gratis) and "with little or no restriction" (libre). see [**Gratis Vs. Libre**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre) and ["Free beer" vs "free speech"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre#.22Free_beer.22_vs_.22free_speech.22_distinction) distinction

  > "Free software is a matter of liberty, not price. To understand the concept, you should think of free as in free speech, not as in free beer." — Richard Stallman
- [Translation of the term "free software"](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/fs-translations.html)

  This is a list of recommended unambiguous translations for the term “free software” (**free as in freedom**) into various languages. Also provided translations of “**gratis software**” in a separate column to show how to make the contrast in various languages.

Comment: Could you add content to your body, rather than referring people to links as your answer?

Comment: @Zizouz212 which content?

Comment: Add information

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I've just tried to improve post

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Definitions are great, but where's the answer to the question: Is the public aware of Free/Libre software rather than freeware?